# split an empty string gives an element

Tags: javascript, split

why `split` on an empty string gives an element?

i.e. how to get `0` in the below case:

```js
let tags = "";
let arr = tags.split(',');
console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: it's in the function specification to return an array with the whole string if the separator is not found. You can still try to find if it exists first with `indexOf` and split only if it is found

Comment: You need to check for empty elements if you want to do that

Comment: @Kaddah and what logic is behind? Why result is not an empty array?

Comment: Try `console.log(arr);` and then you know why. It returns `1`, because of `0: ""`.

Comment: @RezaSaadati, I see but result should be `[]` and not `[""]`

Comment: Logically, it creates an array and populates the first element of that array with everything in the string, up until the first instance of the split character, or it reaches the end of the string.  If you want something different then you just do something different, like `let arr = (tags.indexOf(",") == -1 ? [] : tags.split(',');)`

Comment: @Archer, I see your point, but can't believe that a programming language uses such a stupid logic - `empty divided by nothing = 1`

Comment: That's your understanding of what it does, and that's where the fault is.  It's not dividing anything by anything.  It's doing it the way I described.

Comment: not `dividing` but `spliting` - the same strange logic.

Comment: It's not strange - you've decided it means something it does not.  It starts adding characters to the string at element zero until it reaches the split character (when it increments the index and adds a new empty string) or the end.  It's very clear logic and not even vaguely strange.

Comment: no, of course. If there is `nothing` to split - result of spliting must not be `1`. That's so normal.

Comment: I've explained very clearly how it works.  Just because it doesn't do what you incorrectly assumed it must do (in other words, what you want it to do for your particular use case) then you think it is strange.  It isn't - you simply do not understand it.

Comment: yes, you explained very fine how this logic works. But now you're trying to explain that the logic is right.  And that's the problem. Spliting `nothing` is `nothing` - you say that's a wrong assumption.

Comment: Okay - I'll try one more time because you're missing the point.  It *has* to return the string in the array.  Splitting any string will *always* return at the very least the original string as the 1st element of the resulting array, because *it's still a string, even though it's empty*.  Think about `"bob".split(",")` - Would you expect that to return an empty array?  Regardless of whether you do or not, you now know how it does work so problem solved.

Comment: sometimes precision in the terms, calling things by their names can make think that we are leaving common sense. But common sense is often generalisation. Think about what is really what. An empty string is not nothing. It's a string, it's actually something. And if you don't split a cake in 2, you still have a cake. A whole yummy cake for your own..

Comment: @Kaddath, subject of spliting is not a `string` as `data type`. Subject of spliting is `the content` of that `string`. And it is `emtpy`, i.e. `doesn't exists`.

Comment: @qadenza ...and there lies your misunderstanding.  An empty string **_is_** a string, in all and every programming language.

Comment: Better not try a philosophical-like approach with these kind of things. If it was nothing, you couldn't split it because split function doesn't exist in `null`'s prototype. You can because it is something. You should be happy of this behaviour from split, it allows us to keep the same code in almost all situations, wether the separator is found or not, without having to do a special case for empty strings or not found separators. You can criticize JS conceptors, but not on this precise topic.. because it has a lot of sense practically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the empty `string` elements form `arr` using `filter`

```js
let tags = "";
let arr = tags.split(',').filter(x => x);
console.log(arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just the nature of the `split` function as per the ECMAScript specification. Here is the relevant excerpt from the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.split):

> If the this object is (or converts to) the empty String, the result
>   depends on whether separator can match the empty String. If it can,
>   the result array contains no elements. Otherwise, the result array
>   contains one element, which is the empty String.

A simple workaround for the behavior you're looking for would be something like:

```
let arr = !tags ? [] : tags.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   let tags = "";
   let arr = tags.split(',').filter(x => x);
   console.log(arr.length);
   else 
   {

   var result=console.log(arr.length);
   }
```